# HDF5 multidimmensional array storage

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I got this very simple pandas dataframe with a multidimmensional array:

```py
df_foo = pd.DataFrame({
    'Value': [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
})
```

Here is what's happening when I try to store it in an hdf5 file :

```py
# Using HDFStore:

h5 = HDFStore('foo.h5')
h5.put('foo', df_foo, format='table', data_columns=True)
    #TypeError: Cannot serialize the column [Value] because its data contents are not [string] but [mixed] object dtype


# Using H5py:

h5 = h5py.File('foo.h5','w')
h5.create_dataset('foo', data=df_foo)
    #TypeError: Object dtype dtype('O') has no native HDF5 equivalent
```

I can't find here or on other forums or documentation a satisfactory response to help me. How can I store a multidimmensional array in an hdf5 file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't store a multidimensional array in a pandas Series. So when you create your "array" in your example, you're actually creating a pandas column with `object` dtype, where each element is a python list.

One option for storing a MultiDimensional array as HDF5 is by using [xarray](https://xarray.pydata.org/), another pydata project which extends the pandas concept of labeled indices, but to N dimensions.

The xarray equivalent of your example goes something like this:

```py
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.Dataset({
    "Value": (("x", "y"), [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]),
})

ds.to_netcdf("foo.h5", engine="h5netcdf")
```

This creates a valid HDF5 file using the NetCDF4 standard, using the [`h5netcdf`](https://github.com/h5netcdf/h5netcdf) package, which is built on `h5py`.